# Can we use the command line to get some information within karate framework?

Tags: api, karate

Can we use the command line to get some information within karate framework.

For example using command line to get ipconfig and using that ip running the api call.

getting ip is a basic command but actually need to get some more information using command line.

Any suggestion could help me to understand better.